# SQL Server varchar equality test gives syntax error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a simple table running in SQL Server 2005 defined as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ap_purchases_tax_det](
[invoice_s] [int] NOT NULL,
[line_num] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[tax_code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[tax_type] [varchar](2) NULL,
[tax_det_s] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[old_entity] [varchar](14) NULL,
[old_cc_code] [varchar](5) NULL,
[old_vendor] [varchar](15) NULL,
[old_invoice] [varchar](20) NULL,
[citi] [varchar](1) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [aaaaaap_purchases_tax_det_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [invoice_s] ASC,
    [line_num] ASC,
    [tax_code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The tax_type field is filled with either 'W', 'V', 'B", or '' (this one is not NULL).

I need to get a boolean flag if tax_type is 'W', so I have the SQL:

```
select iif(tax_type = 'W',1,0) FROM dbo.ap_purchases_tax_det;
```

when I run this I get "Incorrect syntax near '='.".  This occurs even for a simple `tax_type = 'W'`.  The test for equality seems to work in the WHERE clause, but I need a flag, which means I would have to UNION together 2 selects.  This is actually part of a join that is a subquery in much larger statement so I don't want to do this.  I have tried excplicitly casting `tax_type = cast('W' as varchar(2))` to no avail. Same results if I use `ISNULL(tax_type,'x')`.

I have no idea why the test for equality is not working, can someone provide guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, write the IIF like this prior to SQL Server 2012

```
select case when tax_type = 'W' then 1 else 0 end
FROM dbo.ap_purchases_tax_det;
```

The CASE statement has another form, but that's like a SWITCH statement in C#/Java or SELECT CASE in MS Access, which is not really a general conditional.

Two important notes about [IIF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)

> > IIF is a shorthand way for writing a CASE statement.
> >     The fact that IIF is translated into CASE...

So when you write

```
IIF ( {condition} , {true} , {false} )
```

The SQL Server query optimizer literally sees

```
CASE WHEN {condition} THEN {true} ELSE {false} END
```

---

FYI You can avoid the CASE statement completely by using this

```
SELECT 1-sign(abs(ascii('W')-ascii(tax_type+'.')))
```

Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `IIF` in SQL 2005 because [IIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) is a SQL 2012 function only

You need to use `CASE`

```
 SELECT CASE tax_type WHEN 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM dbo.ap_purchases_tax_det
```

Comment: `select tax_type = 'W' FROM dbo.ap_purchases_tax_det;` which should return a boolean does not work either.

Comment: @Dr.Drew No. = in a select is a equivalent to an as - it names the column. That will return 'W' each time. Just use `case` as detailed

Comment: So is this why `(CASE WHEN tax_type='W" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` also would not work? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx shows `CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END` is legal)

Comment: Because you're mixing two different quote types

Comment: Ok ok that was only a typo here.  I got the same syntax error using `(CASE WHEN tax_type='W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere. There is nothing wrong with that snippet. Try asking another question. :)